# Google Console warns my app requires CAMERA permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, google-developers-console

I get this error when uploading APK

> You app has an APK with version code 1 which requires the following permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA. Apps that use these permissions in an APK must define privacy policy.

My app does ***not*** use the camera permission. It only uses the Internet permission.

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.MyApp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="My application" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Paste your AndroidMainifest file

Comment: Remove <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  /> from your AndroidnMainifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the camera permission is required by an external library.

Answer (score 0):

use  tools: node remove to that permission if you are maintaining that camera permission in manifest file, use both camera and READ_PHONE_STATE

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  tools:node="remove"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  tools:node="remove"  />
```

Comment: What is the tools namespace?

Comment: go through this below URL https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: you are uploading Apk to playstore first time.If not In first version you have camera permission so add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  tools:node="remove"  /> in second version and " xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" under manifest Tag

Answer (score 0):

If your Manifest contains this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

then please remove it.

Comment: I have showed my full manifest in the question, it does not contain this line.

Comment: Are you trying anywhere in your app to access the camera? Because the error seems like you are using camera and they are asking to add camera permission in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.If Your manifest contain camera permission please remove
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

2.Check Weather you give runtime camera permission or not if yes then remove camera permission.

3.Please check your external library may use camera permission.
```